# $x^{3+ \epsilon} < (\tan x)(\sin x)^{2+ \epsilon}$ holds for all $x \in ({0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}})$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there exists a $\epsilon >0$ such that the inequality $$x^{3+ \epsilon} < (\tan x)(\sin x)^{2+ \epsilon}$$ holds for all $x \in ({0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}})$?

Hint: use Taylor expansion

My attempt: Since $x^{3+ \epsilon} < (\tan x)(\sin x)^{2+ \epsilon} = \dfrac{({\sin x})^{3+ \epsilon}}{\cos x} \leq \dfrac{x^{3+ \epsilon}}{\cos x}$ for all $x \in ({0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}}) \implies \cos x <1$ and this is true for all $x \in ({0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}})$, all $\epsilon >0$ satisfy the inequality.

Is this proof work?

Comment: It does not work. Your argument is simply  assuming that the conclusion is true first, and then getting no contradiction. Such an argument proves nothing.

Comment: Then I suppose the inequality is false first, that means reverse the inequality. Then eventually I get $\cos x >1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: The inequality in the last step cannot be reversed, so you will not get a contradiction.

Comment: You seem to derive only that $x^{3+\epsilon} < \dfrac{x^{3+\epsilon}}{\cos x}$ which is clear, for $0< \cos x < 1$.

Comment: Given the hint, I suggest you compute the Taylor expansion of $(\tan x)(\sin x)^{2+\epsilon}/x^{3+\epsilon}$ around $x=0$. The first nonconstant term should be very informative.

Comment: But when $x=0$, isn't the function undefined?